# Replacing combo box with table widget item in a QTableWidget

Tags: qt

I have a combo box widget in one of the cells of a QTableWidget in my application. After a user selects an option in the combo box, I want to set the selected text as a QTableWidgetItem in the same cell (in which the combo box was present). So I want to replace the existing combo box with a table widget item. Calling removeCellWidget of table widget seems to delete the combo box. How can I achieve this effect without actually deleting the combo box object?

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [takeItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#takeItem). It removes the item from the table without deleting it.